# XHR request -> getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch request that takes a long time (2-5m), but I'm getting this error message in the Chrome console after around 1m30:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So, I tried to wrap my XHR request in a timer, like that:

> client-side code:

```
xhr.open('GET', '/refresh', true); 
xhr.timeout = 600000; 
xhr.onload = function () { 
   window.location.reload(); 
}; 
xhr.send(null);
```

> server-side code:

```
app.get("/refresh", (req, res) => {    
    var process = spawn('python3', ["scrape.py"]);
    process.stdout.on('data', function (data){
        console.log("-> " + data.toString());
        if ((data.toString().indexOf("done") > -1)) {
            res.json({done: "done"});
        }
    });
});
```

**But I'm still getting the same error after around 1m30, and also the console log 'TIMEOUT'.. Why?**

If I run the exact same code with a Python script that lasts 20 seconds, it works perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: what does the response actually return? I noticed Chrome will throw that if the response has status 200 but no response body (including `\n`), which is technically anti-spec (since `\n\n` is used to tell the user agent the response has terminated). So the 1m30 might be an internal Chrome timeout "I got 200 OK, waiting for body, waiting for body waiting for body.." If the endpoint doesn't want to send a body, it must send status 204.

Comment: `window.location.reload` will refetch `/refresh`. It doesn't look like you're using websockets, which means each fetch is stateless, so your client-side timeout does nothing (chrome will timeout waiting for a response since your timeout just reloads the uri).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the browser from timing out due to lack of response, you must send it a response within the timeout (sounds like 90s based on your test). This means your application most likely needs to be redesigned. Since it doesn't look like you're using websockets, everything is stateless and synchronous on the server, so you will have to make the requests pseudo-asynchronous by hand:

The historical pattern is to:

1. Spawned process writes its result somewhere
2. The server should return a token (`/refresh?token=1234`) where when requested, returns the result when the result is ready, otherwise returns something like status 204.
3. Return the token in the initial response
4. In your client, your timeout keeps checking the token, if status == 204, reset the timer, otherwise you have the complete response and break out of the timer.